# SQLite What happens if I skip over putting a value in column

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite table which does not put values in from a string array if there is nothing to retrieve.

here's the code

```
//put values from array index in ContentValues till array[4]
//if array.length exceeds 5 put these values in array[5],[6] etc.

values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, words[0]); //adds to column "name"
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT, words[1]);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DAY1, words[2]);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FROM1, words[3]);
        //change TO1
        if (words[4].equals("0") || words[4].equals("00")){
            words[4]="24";
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TO1, words[4]);
        }else{
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TO1, words[4]);
        }
        System.out.println("this" +Arrays.toString(words));
        //accounting for day 2
        if(words.length>5){
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DAY2, words[5]);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FROM2, words[6]);
            //change TO2
            if (words[7].equals("0") || words[7].equals("00")){
                words[7]="24";
                values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TO2, words[7]);
            }else{
                values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TO2, words[7]);
            }
        }else{
            values.putNull(words[5]);
            values.putNull(words[6]);
            values.putNull(words[7]);
        }
```

when I have values in words[6] and ahead it will make the table but stops making the table after that. Why can't I put null or not put anything at all and still make the table work as not all columns are filled in my table.

Comment: U should add logs, And also see table structure there may be some constrains on column because of that u are unable to leave it blank

Comment: `values.putNull()` expects the column name, not the null value. E.g. `values.putNull(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DAY2)` instead of `values.putNull(words[5])`

Comment: @zap- two things--- should the column be NOT set to not null? does that make a difference?
B) do I really need to putNull? can't it just skip over the value?

Comment: @AhmedZafar depends on whether `values` is used to insert (columns not mentioned have their default values) or to update (columns not mentioned keep their value). You usually don't need to put null explicitly unless you want to override old values / the default.

Comment: @zap-but it's not working without putNull, and also even now the app is crashing, after doing `values.putNull(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DAY2)`